# Calculate how many points are located within certain land cover classes - QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, layers, point-in-polygon, land-cover

I am working on a project for my university and this is my first solo project.

**I have two layers:**

- The first layer is a land cover classification with 6 classes.
- The second layer is a set of points that are locations of a mammal we have been observing.

I have imported the point layer into QGIS using their lat/long and now have them overlaid on top of my land cover classification layer. I now want to understand in which land cover classes these points/observations have occurred.

**If there are around 1000 points, how do I understand how many of them have occurred in each land cover class?**

For example, if there were 12 points located in areas classed as "urban" then this would equate to 12/1000 or 1.2% of sightings of the animal being sighted in urban areas. I can calculate the percentages afterwards myself, but just want to understand how to assign all of the points to the land cover classes they are located within.

Comment: Try "Count points in polygons" from processing toolbox. If needed you can afterwards sum them by class via field calculator.

Comment: Please do not repost Questions  [Calculate percentage of points within land cover classes QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440120/calculate-percentage-of-points-within-land-cover-classes-qgis)

Comment: Hi Vince, I understand, but it's actually a different question, that one was relating to percentages.

Comment: It's the same fundamental problem. Once you have polygon-id as a property of point, counts, percentage, and other statistics are just table math.

Comment: I understand, but I asked that question specifically about calculating percentage and the answer provided was specific to it too. This is more general as you've said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **JOIN ATTRIBUTES BY LOCATION** feature in QGIS.

> Processing toolbox -> Vector General -> Join Attributes by location

Select your point layer for features and the land cover layer for comparison. On join relation type choose **'are within'** and choose the fields (columns) you want to append (say land cover class in your case). Remember to choose the join type wisely (prefer one-to-one) as one-to-many type may lead to multiplication of data points in case your polygons overlap or points fall exactly on shared boundaries. Now you have a point layer with additional information on land cover classes and you can easily perform statistical analysis.

[image: Join attributes by location dialog box]

Comment: This worked absolutely perfectly and quickly! Thank you so much!! :)